# How to unmarshal xml element with colon

Tags: xml, go, xml-namespaces

As the code blow, I could not unmarshal xml element with colon in Go.

https://play.golang.org/p/zMm5IQSfS01

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Obj struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"book"`
    AbcName string   `xml:"abc:name"`
}

func main() {
    a := []byte(`<book><abc:name>text</abc:name></book>`)
    obj := &Obj{}
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(a, obj); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", obj)
}
```

The code outputs:

```
&main.Obj{XMLName:xml.Name{Space:"", Local:"book"}, AbcName:""}
```

Is it possible to unmarshal xml element with colon in Golang? If yes, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`xml.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal)

> *If the XMLName field has an associated tag of the form "name" or
> **"namespace-URL name"**, the XML element must have the given name (and,
> optionally, name space) or else Unmarshal returns an error.*

```
type Obj struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"book"`
    AbcName string   `xml:"abc name"`
    DefName string   `xml:"def name"`
}

func main() {
    a := []byte(`<book><abc:name>text</abc:name><def:name>some other text</def:name></book>`)
    obj := &Obj{}
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(a, obj); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", obj)
}
```